# Display a successful message after connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm using the following code in `C#` to connect to my SQL Server which works fine. But I would like to display a message to the user saying that if the connection was either successful or not and don't know how to do that. Could anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";

private void conectareToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception er) {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
                }

    }
```

Comment: What kind of interface are you using? Is this a wpf, xaml, etc.? What is calling this method? Is it server side or client side?

Comment: If con.Open() fails, the error will get caught and you display the error message. If con.Open() succeeds, your next line of code could display a message box that the connection was successful. is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks like @JaggenSWE beat me to it. You should mark his response as the answer.

Comment: Seeing "SqlConnection" in the same method/class as "MessageBox.Show" makes my eyes hurt.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided the answer yourself. Try the following code:

```
string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";

private void conectareToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection successful !!");    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er) {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection unsuccessful..");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want and I'm not sure if you have any Control that you want to publish the message in, but a simple messagebox would be like this:

```
string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";

private void conectareToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Yay! You're connected!");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception er) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
    }
}
```